# Why angular routes are not working in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angular-ui-router, asp.net-mvc-routing, angularjs-routing

I am new with angularjs, and implementing it in ASP.NET MVC. I read few articles and implement code like below,

this is my layout page,

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>angular demo</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script>
        var schoolModule = angular.module("schoolModule", ['ngRoute']);

        schoolModule.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/one', {
            templateUrl: "Master/One",
            controller: "OneController"
        })
        .when('/two', {
            templateUrl: "Master/Two",
            controller: "TwoController"
        })
        .when('/three', {
            templateUrl: "Master/Three",
            controller: "ThreeController"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: 'Master/One'
        });
    });


        schoolModule.controller("OneController", function ($scope) {
            $scope.message = "One message";
        });


        schoolModule.controller("TwoController", function ($scope) {
            $scope.message = "Two message";
        });


        schoolModule.controller("ThreeController", function ($scope) {
            $scope.message = "Three message";
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="schoolModule">
    <header>Title</header>
    @RenderBody()
    <footer>Footer here</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

My Index page is,

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Master.cshtml";
}
<a href="/#/one">One</a>
<a href="/#/two">Two</a>
<a href="/#/three">Three</a>
<div ng-view>
</div>
```

I have also created 3 partial views, with messages only.

```
<div ng-controller="OneController">
    {{message}}
</div>
```

Here, when I run project, the URL is,

```
http://localhost:52211/Master/index#/Master/one
```

when I click on second button, it redirects me to different controller and action, but url is,

```
http://localhost:52211/#/two
```

and it jumps to Home controller, index action.

Please tell me what mistake I am making here, and how to make it work ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it, If someone is also getting trouble with same thing,

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>angular demo</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script>
        var schoolModule = angular.module("schoolModule", ['ngRoute']);

        schoolModule.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/One', {
                templateUrl: "/Master/One",
                controller: "OneController"
            })
            .when('/two', {
                templateUrl: "/Master/Two",
                controller: "TwoController"
            })
            .when("/three", {
                templateUrl: "/Master/Three",
                controller: "ThreeController"
            });

        });
        schoolModule.controller("OneController", function ($scope, callService, callFactory) {
            //$scope.message = "One message";
            //$scope.message = callService.message();
            $scope.message = callFactory.message();
        });
        schoolModule.controller("TwoController", function ($scope) {
            $scope.message = "Two message";
        });
        schoolModule.controller("ThreeController", function ($scope) {
            $scope.message = "Three message";
        });

        schoolModule.factory("callFactory", function($http){
            var serviceObj = {};
            serviceObj.message = function () {
                return "Result from factory";
            };
            return serviceObj;
        });

        schoolModule.service("callService", function ($http) {
            this.message = function () {
                return "Result from service";
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="schoolModule">

    <header>Title</header>
    @RenderBody()

    <footer>Footer here</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

My Index view is,

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Master.cshtml";
}

<a href="#/One">One</a>
<a href="#/two">Two</a>
<a href="#/three">Three</a>
<ng-view></ng-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `<base>` HTML5 tag. From the [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location):

> **Relative links**
>
> Be sure to check all relative links, images, scripts etc. Angular requires you to specify the url base in the head of your main html file (`<base href="/my-base">`) unless `html5Mode.requireBase` is set to `false` in the html5Mode definition object passed to `$locationProvider.html5Mode()`. With that, relative urls will always be resolved to this base url, even if the initial url of the document was different.

In your layout page, add the base URL with a **trailing slash**. For example:

```
<base href="/Master/index/" />
```

Comment: It made my url clean, but views are not rendered in ng-view div tag.

Comment: When you use the `base` tag, your resources will also be relative to the base so you'll have to update your `templateUrl` accordingly.

Comment: I will try it, and get back to you for sure (Y).

Comment: Solved, without setting base tag and HTML5 mode. My url is bit unclear, but navigation working.

Comment: @KevalPatel that's great! Do you want to post your answer and accept it, in case anybody with the same question can find this?

Comment: sure I will, please wait for some hours, thanks for co-operate

Answer (score 0):

Bro make sure you have  `one`, `two` and  `three` action method with view in `MasterController`.

Keep `<div ng-view></div>` only in `Index` page. It should work properly.